# Codeigniter base url include port generated randomly

Tags: codeigniter-3, phpdesktop

I am using Codeigniter 3 to build an application with PHP Desktop and I am trying to get the base url to execute an ajax script in javascript.

```
$.get( "<?php echo base_url("print_ticket_associate.php"); ?>", { pin: pin, dash : "no", entree : "0", dessert : "0", repas :"1", badge : badge } );
```

Unfortunately, my configuration include random port on http and I need to include this to my base url on codeigniter. This means I can not set it in configuration.

Assuming the page I am trying to execute the script from is : login/match, base url for for codeigniter will be http://localhost/login/match. Which means it is not possible to paste the port after the string.
I want to access http://localhost:randomPort/print_ticket_associate.php

Is there a way to get that port at a specific time in codeigniter page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. But i got the solution. 
Open the settings.json file and change the server port to a fixed port as follows...

```
"web_server": {
        "listen_on": ["127.0.0.1", 8888],
       ..........
}
```

and in codeigniters config.php set the

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/';
```

Note : You can use any number in place of 8888.
Happy coding.

Comment: This is the solution I finally adopted. Thanks

Comment: Welcome. But i got a little better solution. Just use the port 80. Which does not require to use in the base url. Ex. The setting is http://127.0.0.1 with port as 80, then the base url will be only the http://127.0.0.1 or http://localhost/ which doesnot required the port as 80 is default. Thanks

Comment: Its not, many users have there own server running on port 127.0.0.1 80.